# How to add clickable Icons to reactNative navbar

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I want to add clickable icons to my reactnative header component

Currently it looks like this
[image]

next to the title text on the right I want to add an audio symbol but i cant figure out on doing this.

I have seen plenty of answers that work with navigation but Im using drawers so i dnt understand how to add icons.

This is what my code looks like

app.js

```
  <NavigationContainer >
      <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="MetalDetector" screenOptions={{
        drawerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: '#3e4463',
          width: 220
        },
      }}>
        <Drawer.Screen name="MetalDetector" component={Home} options={{drawerLabel: ' MetalDetector'}} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Settings" component={Settings} options={{drawerLabel: ' Settings'}} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Calibrate" component={Home} options={{drawerLabel: ' Calibration'}}/>
        <Drawer.Screen name="Feedback" component={Home} options={{drawerLabel: '‍‍‍ Feedback'}}/>
```

and this is my home.js file which renders content for the metaldetector page

```
 <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
      //Cde is below  
</View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

So where would i add icons to the titlemenu?

I found this here, which covers on how to set the header using stackscreen
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/headers/
but since I use drawer.screen i dont know how to apply that

Comment: You need to create a custom drawer component. Let me share the code.

Comment: where is the code sir?

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:
The DrawerContent file

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Image, Alert, Text } from 'react-native';
import { Title, Drawer } from 'react-native-paper';
import { DrawerContentScrollView, DrawerItem } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import { FontAwesome, MaterialIcons, AntDesign, Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import colors from '../config/colors';

const AppDrawerItem = ({ label , icon, onPress, ...props }) => {
    return (
        <DrawerItem
            icon={icon}
            label={label}
            onPress={onPress}
        />
    );
}
export function DrawerContent(props) {
    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <DrawerContentScrollView {...props}>
                <Drawer.Section style={styles.drawerSection}>
                    <AppDrawerItem
                        onPress={() => { setIsDeletePressed(false); props.navigation.navigate('Dashboard') }}
                        label="Dashboard"
                        icon={({ color, size, focused }) => (
                            <MaterialIcons
                                name="dashboard"
                                color={focused ? colors.primary : color}
                                size={size}
                            />
                        )}
                        {...props}
                    />
                    <AppDrawerItem
                        onPress={() => { setIsDeletePressed(false); props.navigation.navigate('Messages') }}
                        label="Messages"
                        icon={({ color, size, focused }) => (
                            <MaterialIcons
                                name="notifications"
                                color={focused ? colors.primary : color}
                                size={size}
                            />
                        )}
                        {...props}
                    />

                </Drawer.Section>
            </DrawerContentScrollView >
        </View >
    );
}
```

DrawerNavigator

```
        <Drawer.Navigator
        screenOptions={{
            headerTitleStyle: {
                color: "black",
                opacity: 0.9
            },
            headerTintColor: colors.primary,
            swipeEnabled: false,
            headerTitleAlign: 'center',
            headerShadowVisible: false,
        }} drawerContent={props => <DrawerContent {...props} />} > //---here you can add drawercontent component
        <Drawer.Screen name="Dashboard" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Drawer.Screen options={{ headerShown: true }} name="Messages" component={NotificationNavigator} />
    </Drawer.Navigator >
```

Edit:
Option2:
You can add the icon in the <Drawer.Screen> tag.

```
<Drawer.Screen name="Feed" component={Feed}  options={{
       title: 'Home',
       drawerIcon: ({focused, size}) => (
          <Ionicons
             name="md-home"
             size={size}
             color={focused ? '#7cc' : '#ccc'}
          />
       ),
    }} />
```

Comment: Yes, there is. I have edited the above answer.

Comment: Dude, im not trying to change the drawer Icon, i try to add a icon to the topbar, next to metaldetector

Comment: Sorry for the misleading. Do you want to change the hamburger icon on specific screen or overall on all screens?

Comment: This might help you. https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/1122